# Highcharts - load and refresh csv

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, highcharts

I have 2 Charts (using Highcharts) with different data on one page.
The data to visualize comes from CSV files.
My Code works so far, and the Charts show the CVS content visualized.
But: I need to reload the CSV every 5 Minutes, cause new data gets written in these CSV files every 5 Minutes. 
How do I perform that reload in the best way? 
My code to generate the 2 Charts:

```
$.get('chart_1.csv', function(csv) {
 $('#chart_1').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    data: {
        csv: csv
    }
 });
});

$.get('chart_2.csv', function(csv) {
 $('#chart_2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    data: {
        csv: csv
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval`, put your ajax inside the function.

```
function function1() {
    //do your AJAX stuff here
}
setInterval(function1, 300000); //300000 MS == 5 minutes
```

If you want to show the graph on load use this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
//ajax function here
}
```

[Reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529783/how-do-you-set-interval-to-ajax-call-in-jquery)

Comment: I`ve had that so far, thank you. That works for the reload, but when enter the page first the user has to wait for the setIntervall. The interval should start to fire after data is first loaded.

Comment: You can use the function twice, on window load and on the set interval.

Comment: This is where my Javascript/Ajax knowlege ends. And is it a performant way to do so?

Comment: Try the updated answer, include jQuery library in your code.

Comment: That works - thank you. Is there a way to check if chart_1.csv has changed, and if so load the file again?

Comment: Nope, you need to load file and compare content with previous.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to read updated csv files every time. Default, ajax requests use cache. You can change that by using: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
This is the way to do it when using implicit ajax requests like $.get. Otherwise, just add "cache: false" in your ajax statements list.